# how to prove it is a brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I was struggling with this question for a while now:

Let the process $(B(t))_{t\ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and suppose $c>0$ is a constant. Let τ be a stopping time such that $B(τ)=c$ and $B(u)<c$ for all $u<τ$.

$$Z(u)=\begin{cases} B(u) &\text{if }0\le u<τ , \\2c−B(u) &\text{if }u>τ\end{cases}$$

I did two things:

-I was struggling when showing $Z(s+t)-z(s)$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $t$
I struggle when I try to work on the case where s+t>τ and s<τ
in which I ended up with $2c-B(s+t)-B(s)$ where I have no idea how to prove it is normally distributed mean $0$ variance $t$

-I then tried to work on the $Z(u)$ itself for $0\le u<τ$ it was not a problem as $Z(u)=B(u)$, then for $u>\tau $ I said $2c−B(u)=2B(\tau )−B(u)$.

Let $u=x+\tau$, then $ = 2B(\tau)−B(\tau +x)$. Here I wanted to use this lemma  "For any $s \ge  0$, $(B(t + s) − B(s))_{t\ge 0}$ is a Brownian motion", but the constant doesn't let me.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Please use LaTeX, it'll look better.

Comment: [Reflection principle for brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process))